# Docker - what is the point of few same services on same node?

Tags: docker

I am reading this http://training.play-with-docker.com/orchestration-hol/

Here we have 3 swarm nodes. As I understand - one node is for one machine. If one machine/node fails, 2 of them are still running.

But why we are creating 7 services if there are still only 3 machines? As I understand each node has equal amount of services, but since 7 does not divide by 3, one node will have more services.

But if the node fails, then all of those services fail which are on that node.

So why not having 3 services - one for each node?

Comment: Maybe each node has multiple processors and the services don't natively scale beyond a single processor?

Comment: I guess this is the same, only different title so that I did not find earlier. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040555/in-docker-swarm-mode-is-there-any-point-in-replicating-a-service-more-than-the-n?rq=1 and BMitch asnwer makes sense for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a tutorial. The replicas number of 7 is not really relevant.

Normally, the services replicas will be evenly distributed on a each node in the swarm. Some nodes in the swarm might be more powerful than others. In such cases you may choose to restrict more services to run on those nodes.

Also note that in case a node goes down, swarm will attempt to meet the service replica number by starting a new container on available nodes.

But again, the number of replicas chosen in this tutorial is not relevant. The tutorial is demonstrating how to scale a service and what happens once a node is drained.